# Samsung galaxy s5 battery Drainig fast

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-5

My device is the Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-9000H. Its battery drains very fast, even when the screen is off. It drains 70% overnight. The battery level becomes only 10% in the next morning, although the phone would've done nothing overnight!

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Have you checked in *Settings › Battery Usage* what app might be responsible for it?

Comment: +1 to @Izzy, this is key. It could be a misbehaving app that you downloaded, or a misbehaving system app, in which case Norman's answer may be your best bet.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf in both cases you mention it may be sufficient to simply reset that app (*Settings › Apps,* tap the app's entry, "clear cache" might already cure it, or with less luck "delete data" at the same place). Following Norman's advice, OP would lose *all data* including user-installed apps and device configuration. And if the issue pops up again afterwards, there's no comparison possible as the facts haven't been collected in the first place.

Comment: I have smart manager installed in my phone. daily at night i cleaned all in it. but after that battery drains fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `Battery Draining` Problem is also Solved by upgrading Android `lollipop 5.0.1` to `marshmallow 6.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if one app is draining a lot of battery in the settings (like someone already mentioned). If there is an app that does that, uninstall it or turn it off completely when you don't need it.

If there's no such app or the battery is still draining fast, you also might need a new battery, depending on how old your current one is. A normal battery has an average lifetime of 2-3 years, after that it sometimes starts to malfunction, like draining very fast or just loosing all the energy all the sudden. If that's the case, you're gonna need to go out and buy a new battery - it doesn't cost much, ~25€. Also a good tip for having your battery live longer: Use only chargers which are specifically for your phone/battery. Other chargers might work as well, but if they give nit enough energy, your phone will charge slowly, and, even worse, if they give too much energy, it will charge very quickly **but** because the battery isn't made for that much energy, it'll break much sooner.

Comment: I got one too, 100% at 11pm, 0% at 6am<br>
Just replace it with 13$ OEM battery. Everything is fine.

Comment: I don't think so, it is battery problem.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that my battery drains faster if i forget to turn off bluetooth when i'm not using it.

Like the advice above says, check your battery usage to find out whats draining it so much.

Answer (score 0):

Several things could be causing this. For example:

1.) The battery being too old. (These things do have a shelf life - ~2-3 years.)

2.) When you first got the phone, you may have had the phone plugged too frequently. Your exuberance can shorten the life expectancy of the battery. (Understandably, you don't want to run out of power when you need it, but you need to give the phone charging a break.)

3.) You may have applications that needlessly run all the time. Some apps continually ping servers for the latest information / updates / messages / location / etc. Take a look at those unnecessary programs and either shut them down or control them. If you did find some apps that could be a problem, determine whether you need to be updated all the time even while you're asleep. If you've found some of those apps, then I would check your wireless phone bill to see if your "data usage" is running high. I have found that those offending apps might be pickpocketing you. On the upside, your wireless carrier is always willing to sell you more "data".   ;-)

For example, any application that requires your phone's "Location" setting to be set to "on." (e.g. Facebook, MapQuest, GoogleMaps, etc.)

4.) I am sure there are more...

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Backup your information and do a factory reset.  That should clear up any issues you are having with the software.

[S5 hard reset guide](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/factory-reset-galaxy-s5/)

If the battery is still draining quickly, then you should try and replace the battery.  If this does not solve the issue, then their may be an issue with the device itself and will require you to take it to a repair shop for inspection.

Good luck!

Comment: Norman, that's drawing conclusions without having facts. Sure it *might* cure the issue – but at high costs (you should at least have mentioned this deletes *all* user settings, apps and data). But it might be simply enough to reset a single misbehaving app. You throw a bomb where a swatter might have been sufficient.